# How to solve Chinese Remainder Theorem with exponantial values

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, euclidean-algorithm

I need help solving this Chinese Remainder Theorem, but I would like to solve it using Euclid's Algorithm.

\begin{align*}
  2x &\equiv 4^{2010} \pmod{3} \\
  15x &\equiv 13 \pmod{4} \\
  3x &\equiv (-29) \pmod{5}
\end{align*}

I know how to solve regular exercises like this, I don't know how to solve a congruence with exponent using Euclid's Algorithm. So, if anyone could help me solve the first congruence with Euclid's Algorithm, that would be great. Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Your particular example is trivial because $4^{2010} \equiv 1^{2010} =1 \pmod 3$

Answer (score 0):

As @Deepak commented, the first congruence boils down to $2x \equiv -x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, the second to $15x \equiv -x \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and the third to $3x \equiv 1 \pmod 5$.
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I would like to solve the first congruence using Euclid's Algorithm, I don't always see the result just by looking at a congruence, so I've been using Euclid's Algorithm to solve them. But I don't know how to use it for the first congruence.

Comment: @luchka13 Do you mean using Euclid to compute the inverse of the leading coefficients $\,2,15,3?\,$ Please describe how you tried to solve the first congruence so we can see *exactly* where you got stuck.

Comment: i know how to make the second and third congruence with Euclid's Algorithm, and i get the correct answers, but I have no idea how to do that with the first one

Comment: @luchka13 Agaim *precisely* where are you stuck?  At $\, 4^n\equiv 1^n\equiv 1\pmod{3}?\ $

Comment: i do all these congruences with Euclid's Algorithm, so the second and third congruence don't cause me any problems, the first one, though, i don't even know how to start.. i do them EXACTLY like this video shows. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-HSjLXrfPs But i don't know how to do the first one. are the steps the same or what?